# Relationship between rxJava and promises

Tags: java, promise, rx-java

I'm trying to relate rxJava to what I already know, particularly from JavaScript programming.  Is the core idea of rxJava like promises on observables?

Comment: No, because promises can only be resolved once. An observable can notify its consumers multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comment explain, a promise will allow you to chain operation, but in the end, you'll get one result.

With RxJava, you can be notified multiple time and then get multiple result.

Promise can be seen as async operation, and Observable as async* operation.